# Is there any way to hide Bonjour AFP services from one network port or IP pool only?

Tags: mac, networking, airport, bonjour, afp

I've got two Mac OS machines networked via ethernet, one with 10.5, one 10.6. They have self-assigned IPs, and I want to keep using AFP that way. However, for internet access, we're on a public WiFi network and would rather not have our machines show up on any other Macs which happen to be on the wireless.

Is there any way we can still file share via ethernet but not appear over Airport?